# Convert a single column to multiple in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a single column of data in SQL Sever and need to expand this to multiple (2) columns.

The raw data looks like so:

```
Col1
-------
Monday
Jon
Boris
Natalie
Tuesday
James
Tom
Boris
```

I'd like it to look like this:

```
Name   | Day
-------+---------
Jon    | Monday
Boris  | Monday
Natalie| Monday
James  | Tuesday
Tom    | Tuesday
Boris  | Tuesday
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you know the `Jon` is to be tied to `Monday`, etc?  Is it due to the way they are listed in the table?  Data in a table is not inherently ordered, do you have a column that will keep the data in this order - an identity column?

Comment: Yes, It's imported from a text file list. So everyone under Monday is Monday and every one under Tuesday is Tuesday. Assuming I import the data in order line by line I can eailsy and a ID column that increments.

Comment: Personally, I would create a second table with the days of the week, give them a technical key, and link them with FK, rather than repeating the name of the day in every record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are going to be able to add that identity column to source table for ordering and that  your table will look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (id int identity(1,1), Col1 NVARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO Table1 (Col1)
VALUES 
    ('Monday'),('Jon'),('Boris'),('Natalie'),
    ('Tuesday'),('James'),('Tom'),('Boris')
```

You can try the following:

- First create a temp table for weekdays so you can distinguish them
  (can also be done in other ways)
- Join days back with original table looking for larger IDs (t.ID > d1.ID)
- Prevent those that should go in the next day ID (t.ID < MIN(d2.Id))
- Coalesce is there just to make sure it works for the last day in the list.

.

```
CREATE TABLE #weekDays (wd NVARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO #weekDays
VALUES 
    ('Monday'), ('Tuesday'), ('Wednesday'), 
    ('Thursday'), ('Friday'), ('Saturday'), ('Sunday');

WITH CTE_Days AS
(
    SELECT t.*
    FROM Table1 t
    INNER JOIN #weekDays wd ON wd.wd = t.col1
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE_Days d1
INNER JOIN Table1 t ON t.id > d1.id AND t.id < 
    COALESCE((
        SELECT MIN(d2.id)
        FROM CTE_Days d2
        WHERE d2.id > d1.id
    ), t.id + 1)
```

Comment: That's a brilliant answer thank you so much! I had quite a long routine set up involving variables and while loops. It was awful!

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (Col1 NVARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @temp (Col1)
VALUES 
    ('Monday'),('Jon'),('Boris'),('Natalie'),
    ('Tuesday'),('James'),('Tom'),('Boris')

;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 
          Col1
        , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1/0) % 4
        , rn2 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1/0)
    FROM @temp
)
SELECT 
      [Day] = t.Col1
    , Name = t2.Col1 
FROM cte t
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT *
    FROM cte t2
    WHERE t2.rn2 BETWEEN t.rn2 + 1 AND t.rn2 + 3
) t2
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

**Output:**

[image: output]

Comment: That certainly does what I want the only issue is if we have variable numbers of people on various days. So if we add 'Mike' to the list for 'Monday' it breaks. I'm thinking that in that case I'll probably need to do a loop and count the number of people in each section.